# Embedding Facebook in blog post not working

Tags: posts, facebook, embed

there once was this feature of embedding Facebook status posts simply by entering the URL [see here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/facebook-integration/facebook-embeds) <strike>[or here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/embed-facebook-status-posts-wordpress/)</strike> (**edited**: apparently I misunderstood the content of that blog post).

So now I am trying to use it and it works fine with Instagram and Twitter (after I updated to WP 4.4).

Is this feature discontinued? Or did FB change something on their API so this doesn't work? In my blog, I even can't get the *sample FB post* mentioned in the WP.com post linked above.

Comment: Are you on wordpress.com ?

Comment: ... nope. self-hosted. But since the other variants for Instagram, Twitter, YouTube was working, I assumed that FB would works same way, too.